# How to get current filters from PowerBi embedded export report

Tags: powerbi-embedded

I am using powerbi embedded and I would like an export button similar to the one used on powerbi.com, that asks if you want to apply the current filters or not.

How can I get the current filters in javaScript in such a way that these can be passed to the back end, or to the javascript api to generate a PDF?

I am using the following code to generate the PDF currently, I just don't know how to get the current configuration current filters and current page selected in javaScript

```
   public PowerBiExportViewModel CreateExport(Guid groupId,
        Guid reportId,
        IEnumerable<PowerBiReportPage> reportPages,
        FileFormat fileFormat,
        string urlFilter,
        TimeSpan timeOut)
    {
        var errorMessage = string.Empty;
        Stream stream = null;
        var fileSuffix = string.Empty;

        var securityToken = GetAccessToken();

        using (var client = new PowerBIClient(new Uri(BaseAddress), new TokenCredentials(securityToken, "Bearer")))
        {
            var powerBiReportExportConfiguration = new PowerBIReportExportConfiguration
            {
                Settings = new ExportReportSettings
                {
                    Locale = "en-gb",
                    IncludeHiddenPages = false
                },
                Pages = reportPages?.Select(pn => new ExportReportPage { PageName = pn.Name }).ToList(),
                ReportLevelFilters = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(urlFilter) ? new List<ExportFilter>() { new ExportFilter(urlFilter) } : null,
            };

            var exportRequest = new ExportReportRequest
            {
                Format = fileFormat,
                PowerBIReportConfiguration = powerBiReportExportConfiguration
            };

            var export = client.Reports.ExportToFileInGroupAsync(groupId, reportId, exportRequest).Result;
```

Comment: Probably you should use a bookmark (e.g. in [PowerBIReportExportConfiguration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/reports/exporttofile#powerbireportexportconfiguration)), which can be captured using the [API](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Bookmarks).

Answer (score 0):

You can go to [PowerBi playground](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/v2-demo/index.html#) and play around with their sample report. Next to "Embed" button you have "Interact" and option to get filters. In response you get JSON with filters. If you are too lazy to go there, here is the code it created for me

```
// Get a reference to the embedded report HTML element
var embedContainer = $('#embedContainer')[0];

// Get a reference to the embedded report.
report = powerbi.get(embedContainer);

// Get the filters applied to the report.
try {
    const filters = await report.getFilters();
    Log.log(filters);
}
catch (errors) {
    Log.log(errors);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have looked at this and it doesn't look to be in a suitable format for me to pass to the export API call which is asking for only one report level filter string.